# Button to Select Multiple IDs Based on Amount

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to create a button that adds unique items on click.  I basically do a query which will give me unique items (or in this case, "ids") for a category.  I represent the total amount of the available ids in the query as the quantity.  What I want to do is create a button that will select each id based on the quantity selected.

So for instance, say $id is our variable, and I do an implode (in php):
`implode(",", $id)`

Let's say the result will give me the ids of 4,6,7,8,9,10.

If I wanted to select a quantity of 4 (the quantity is represented by a select box), and had an Add button - how do I get the button to automatically select ids 4,6,7,8?  Or say if the quantity was 2, then the add button select ids 4,6?  The order at which the Add button selects ids doesn't really matter as long as the button selects the ids based on the amount given.

Comment: a bit of demo code if you had any would have been helpful to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$quantity = 4;
$list = [4,6,7,8,9,10];
echo implode(',', array_slice($list, 0, $quantity));
```